# Scylla driver with Spark cassandra connector

Tags: spark-cassandra-connector, scylla

In our use case, we used Scylla driver + ScyllaDB along with Spark Cassandra connector on Spark application. Currently, we're using Scylla driver **3.7.1-scylla-2**, which is pretty old like end of year 2019.

In our pom file, you can see the dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scylladb</groupId>
    <artifactId>scylla-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1-scylla-2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scylladb</groupId>
    <artifactId>scylla-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1-scylla-2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now we're trying to upgrade the Scylla driver version to latest like **3.11.2.0**, and we made the change in pom file as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scylladb</groupId>
    <artifactId>scylla-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scylladb</groupId>
    <artifactId>scylla-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

After upgrading the Scylla driver version, while running our spark job, seeing errors as below:

```
2023-03-17 00:11:17,122 ERROR [org.apache.spark.executor.Executor] - <Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)>
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata.getReplicas(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/util/Set;
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.findReplicas(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:48)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.tokenAwareQueryPlan(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:57)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:73)
at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.PagingOptimizingLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan(PagingOptimizingLoadBalancingPolicy.java:69)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.<init>(RequestHandler.java:147)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:715)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:148)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:37)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:37)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ebates.pcs.commons.sparkutil.ListingSparkUtils.getListingData(ListingSparkUtils.java:471)
at com.ebates.rcp.itemmaster.sparkjobs.MerchantPushJob$1.apply(MerchantPushJob.java:333)
at com.ebates.rcp.itemmaster.sparkjobs.MerchantPushJob$1.apply(MerchantPushJob.java:318)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.$anonfun$withSessionDo$1(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
at com.ebates.rcp.itemmaster.sparkjobs.MerchantPushJob.lambda$merchantPush$d9b9cfa9$1(MerchantPushJob.java:318)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$adapted(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea on how to fix this, which version of Scylla driver + Spark cassandra connector should I use to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Spark Cassandra Connector to a version that uses a compatible Cassandra driver like `2.5.1 or later` which should include a Cassandra driver that is compatible with `Scylla driver 3.11.2.0`

pom example:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After updating, run the application. If issue still persists, check for other version conflicts in dependencies and try to resolve them accordingly.